# Artifacts appear in final render, but not in preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, artifacts

I'm trying to do a simple cup, I have reduced the materials to an absolute minimum of nodes, so the issue probably isn't in the material. The rendered view in the viewport looks like this:
[image: preview]

but the final render like this:
[image: final render]

Tried to fix normals, remove doubles, looked for duplicate objects, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: That looks like z-fighting to me. If it is only in the final render, have a look at your modifiers, something is duplicating your mesh.

Comment: Duplicated geometry indeed. Look in the outliner window for any objects that are disabled for viewing in the viewport (eye icon) but are enabled for rendering (camera Icon).

Comment: @sambler Thank you, I don't know why but I had a boolean modifier on the handle.